# rle compression algorithm java

Tags: java, compression

I have to do a RLE algorithm in java with the escape character (Q)

Example 1 if i have an input like:

```
77777 => 57
BBBBBBBBB => 10B
FBFB8923 => 004FBFB8923
2365553422 => 005236555342200
```

this is the code that i made:

```
public String coderRLE(string text) {
            String res = new String();
            char[] charArray = text.toCharArray();
            char caractere = 0;
            int num = 0;
            int i = 0;
            for (char c : charArray) {
                if (c != caractere && i != 0) {
                    if (num >= 2) {
                        res += num;
                        res += caractere;
                    } else {
                        res += caractere;
                    }
                    num = 1;
                } else {
                    num++;
                }
                caractere = c;
                i++;
            }
            if (num >= 2) {
                res += num;
                res += caractere;
            } else {
                res += caractere;
            }
            return res;
    }

public String decoderRLE(String text) {
            String res = new String();
            char[] charArray = text.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0;i<charArray.length-1;i++) {
                char s = charArray[i];
                if (!Character.isDigit(s)) {
                    res += s;
                } else {
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s));
                    for (int j = 0; j < num - 1; j++) {
                        res += charArray[i+1];
                    }
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
```

the problem is with number like thisaaabbcccc666iii => aaabbcccc6633333ii

Comment: You don't describe the problem you have with a "number like this" and there is no actual question regarding that problem. Is it about numeric characters? Encoding or Decoding? What do you think what is going wrong? Etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
public static String encode(String source) {
    StringBuffer dest = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        int runLength = 1;
        while (i+1 < source.length() && source.charAt(i) == source.charAt(i+1)) {
            runLength++;
            i++;
        }
        dest.append(runLength);
        dest.append(source.charAt(i));
    }
    return dest.toString();
}
```

if the input is `aaabbcccc666iii` it compress it as `3a2b4c363i`

```
String example = "aaabbcccc666iii";
System.out.println(encode(example));
```

*Output*

```
3a2b4c363i
```